# Smallest $n$ such that with a probability of 90% or more, the inspection is completed before the arrival of the next item

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

Here is the question:

> An inspector selects every nth item in a production line for a detailed inspection. Suppose that the time between item arrivals is an exponential random variable with mean 1 minute,and suppose that it takes 2 minutes to inspect an item. Find the smallest value of $n$ such that with a probability of 90%  or more, the inspection is completed before the arrival of the next item that requires inspection.

I really don't understand the question. If $Z$ is the time between two arrivals, then we want $\mathbb{P}[Z\gt 2]\gt 0.9$ if $t$ is in minutes. So what is the importance of $n$ here? Where does it affect? According to the question, is it true that $\mathbb{P}[Z = t] = e^{-t}$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$? I'm confused about this question and also the Poisson distribution which I think is related to the question.

Comment: The time between arrivals has exponential distribution, so consider one item arrives, the time until the next item arrives is exponentially distributed. And the question is, whether or not the inspection (taking 2min) will be done before the next n items arrive. Well the time you have until the n-th item arrives, is the time until the n-1 th item arrives plus the (exponentially distributed time) between the n-th and n-1 th. So you consider the sum of n exponentially distributed variables

Comment: Though, the sum of exponential distributed random variables is gamma distributed, not poisson

Comment: @FelixB. Can you explain the question in terms of random variable please? I can't understand it.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? (See answer)

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_k$ bet the arrival time of the n-th item. Then according to the text, the time between the arrivals
$$\delta_k = T_k-T_{k-1} \sim \text{Exp}(1),$$
is exponentially distributed. If every n-th item is inspected, then an inspection of the K-th item means, that the next item inspected is the K+n-th.

The inspection of the K-th item starts at arrival (i.e. at $T_K$). Since the inspection takes 2 minutes, the inspection finishes at $T_K+2$.
So the question is, what is the smallest n, such that the next item arrives after the inspection finish with 90% probability? I.e. find
$$n^* = \min\{n\in\mathbb{N}: P(T_{K+n} >T_K+2)>0.9\}$$

And 
$$\begin{align}P(T_{K+n} >T_K+2) 
&= P\left(T_K+\sum_{k=K+1}^n T_k-T_{k-1} > T_K+2\right)\\
&=P\left(\sum_{k=K+1}^n \delta_k > 2\right)
\end{align}$$

Where $\sum_{k=K+1}^n \delta_k \sim \Gamma(n, 1)$ since sums of exponential distributed random variables are gamma distributed.